# custom facebook login button leaves blank login popup

Tags: facebook, permissions, facebook-login

I started using a custom facebook login button by calling FB.login and it works ok when tested it with a browser already logged into facebook (it asks for the permissions) except that the popup does not close after its work is done, I end up with a blank popup with this url  https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/extended
This is happening on firefox and chrome, didn't try others yet.

When tested with a browser not already logged into facebook I get the same sort of problem after the sign in page - blank popup and no prompts for permissions.

Is there an event I have to catch that the SDK would catch for me if I did not use a custom button?
Is there a good guide to using a custom button for facebook login or is it not allowed? I'm guessin the lack of the usual facebook elements ( fb:login-button...  div class="fb-login-button") on my page are throwing off the SDK.   Do I need to skip the SDK just to have a custom button?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, sorry.  I was looking deep into facebook apis when the problem was that in my button's onclick I forgot to return false, so the button click reloaded the page and that broke stuff I guess by invalidating various facebook api internal references.  Just changing onclick function to return false fixed my problem. see code for new line:

```
        $("#linkfacebook").click(function() {
            FB.login(function(response) {}, {scope: 'publish_stream,manage_pages'});
            return false;  // this is the new line that fixed the problem
        });
```